# Repeat columns on a table according to name

Tags: r, data.table

I was given one of those Excel epic examples. The wide table states the capacity for pairs of product (in the rows) and machines (in the columns). The table looks similar to the one in the next reproducible example (please note the use of `data.table`. `data.frame` / tidyverse solutions are welcome, although `data.table` solutions are preferred):

```
a <- data.table(names = c("product 1", "product 2"), "9-10" = c(1, 5), "21-23" = c(3, 2))

> a
       names 9-10 21-23
1: product 1    1     3
2: product 2    5     2
```

The problem is "9-10" means machines 9 and 10 have the same capacities (1 and 5 for products 1 and 2, respectively). I'm looking for a way to end with a table that looks like `b`:

```
> b
       names 9 10 21 23
1: product 1 1  1  3  3
2: product 2 5  5  2  2
```

I achieved it with the following code:

```
for (i in unlist(strsplit(names(a)[2:3], split = "-", fixed = TRUE))){
    a[, print(i) := .SD, .SDcols = grep(paste0(i, "\\b"), names(a)[2:3], value = TRUE)]
}

a[, names(a)[2:3] := NULL]
```

I wonder what would be a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility with `data.table`:

```
melt(a, id = 1)[, unlist(tstrsplit(variable,'-')), by = .(names, value)
                ][, dcast(.SD, names ~ V1)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>        names 10 21 23 9
> 1: product 1  1  3  3 1
> 2: product 2  5  2  2 5
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` we can just create an index and subset, then adjust names afterwards.

```
# data
a <- data.table(names = c("product 1", "product 2"),
                "9-10" = c(1, 5),
                "21-23" = c(3, 2))


# names split
name_pos <- strsplit(names(a), split = "-")
# create index for subsetting based on name_pos
index <- rep(seq_along(name_pos), times = lengths(name_pos))

# index and adjust names
a_final <- a[, ..index]
# thanks to Frank for suggestion
setnames(a_final, unlist(name_pos))
```

Comment: The data.table-ish version of the last line would be `setnames(a, unlist(name_pos))`

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use `tidyr` as:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
a %>% gather(variable, value, -names) %>% 
  separate(variable, c("col1","col2")) %>% mutate(value2 = value) %>%
  spread(col1, value)  %>% spread(col2, value2) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  summarise_all(sum,na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#       names 21 9 10 23
# 1 product 1  3 1  1  3
# 2 product 2  2 5  5  2
```